# Does a compact connected complete linear order have the fixed point property?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, order-theory, connectedness, fixed-point-theorems

Would the same arguments used for showing $[0,1]$ has the fixed point property hold in this general case?  What could go wrong?

EDIT: The fixed point property can be interpreted in two ways that I am now aware of:

i) A partially ordered set has the fixed point property if every increasing self-map has a fixed point.

ii) A linearly ordered topological space has the fixed point property if every continuous self-map has a fixed point.

My question has been answered positively in the case of (i). I am also interested in knowing what happens if we interpret FPP as in (ii).

Comment: What is the fixed point property?

Comment: Let me know if I am wrong but, $x_{i+1} = T(x_i)$ with $T(x) = x/2$ does not have a fixed point in $0$? for whatever initial condition in $[0, 1]$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Theorem (Tarski): If $(X,\leq)$ is a complete linear order, then every weakly increasing function $f: X \rightarrow X$ has a fixed point.

You can prove this using the **Principle of Ordered Induction** [see Theorem 4 here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/realinduction.pdf), which is the generalization of **Real Induction** (Proposition 1 of *loc. cit.*) to any Dedekind Complete linearly ordered set.

(Recall that a linear order is Dedekind complete if every nonempty subset which is bounded above has a least upper bound; equivalently, every nonempty subset which is bounded below has a greatest lower bound.  A linear order is complete if *every* subset has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound: this is equivalent to Dedekind complete plus the existence of top and bottom elements.)

The result when $X = [a,b]$ (a closed bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$) is proved using Real Induction in Theorem 6.22 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf).  That proof works verbatim for any complete linear order.

Other comments:

1. In fairness I should mention also the more standard approach: show that $\operatorname{sup} \{x \in X \mid f(x) \geq x\}$ is a fixed point.  This is quite straightforward, maybe even more so than the above approach.
2. If you equip a linear order with the order topology, then it is compact iff it is complete, and it is connected iff it is Dedekind complete and dense (if $x < z$ there is $y$ with $x < y< z$).  This is also pleasant to prove using ordered induction: see [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/induction_completeness_brief.pdf).  So you are assuming more than you need to: complete implies compact, and connected is neither necessary nor sufficient.
3. As Asaf points out, the result is a special case of the [Knaster-Tarski Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem): that theorem applies to a complete lattice rather than a complete *linear* order and asserts that the set of fixed points, in addition to being nonempty, forms a sublattice.
4. The fixed-point property characterizes completeness in lattices:

> [Theorem (Anne C. Davis)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103044539) Let $X$ be a lattice in which every weakly increasing function $f: X \rightarrow X$ has a fixed point.  Then $X$ is complete.

Actually Davis's Theorem is quite a bit harder to prove than the Knaster-Tarski Theorem.

**Added**: Niels Diepeveen in the comments points out that the "fixed point property" might be: "Does every *continuous* (for the order topology) function $f: X \rightarrow X$ have a fixed point?"  That's a different question.  The following is an **incomplete** answer.

> Proposition: Let $X$ be a nonempty linearly ordered set endowed with the order topology.
> a) If $X$ is complete and connected, then every continuous $f: X \rightarrow X$
> has a fixed point.
> b) If every continuous function $f: X \rightarrow X$ has a fixed point, then $X$ is connected.

Proof: a) Suppose that $X$ is complete but that there is a continuous $f: X \rightarrow X$ which does not have a fixed point.  We'll show that $X$ is not connected.  Let $X_1 = \{x \in X \mid f(x) < x\}$ and $X_2 = \{x \in X \mid f(x) > x\}$.  Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are open, and -- since there are no fixed points --
$X_1 \cup X_2 = X$.  Moreover the bottom element $0$ lies in $X_2$ and the top element $1$ lies in $X_1$, so we get a separation of $X$.
b) If $X = X_1 \coprod X_2$ is a separation of $X$, let $x_i \in X_i$ for $i = 1,2$,
and define $f: X \rightarrow X$ by mapping every point in $X_1$ to $x_2$ and every point in $X_2$ to $x_1$.  $f$ is locally constant hence continuous, but has no fixed point.

What remains is to determine whether every continuous function $f: X \rightarrow X$
having a fixed point implies that $X$ is complete.

Comment: Isn't this really a consequence of the Knaster-Tarski theorem?

Comment: Would it be correct to say a Dedekind-complete order is complete if it is non-Archimedean?

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, it is a special case of the Knaster-Tarski theorem.  (The latter allows "linear order" to be relaxed to "lattice", and has the stronger conclusion that the nonempty set of fixed points forms a complete sublattice.)  In my notes I call it "Tarski's Theorem".  I have included that in my answer: thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @David: "non-Archimedean" makes sense only with additional structure, e.g. at least that of a linearly ordered *group* (and more commonly, a linearly ordered field).  Then: no, a Dedekind-complete ordered field must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, which is Archimedean.

Comment: Ok, last question.  I am familiar with constructing the Dedekind completion, but not the completion in the stronger sense.  Am I correct in my observation that usually "complete" usually means only "Dedekind complete"? Does every linear order admit a completion?

Comment: Again, the only difference between complete and Dedekind complete is that complete means Dedekind complete plus having top and bottom elements.  For an ordered field we can't have top or bottom elements: for all $x \in F$, $x+1 > x$, $x-1 < x$, so Dedekind completeness is the desirable property.  (However it is still dangerous to just say "complete", because now there is something else called **Cauchy completeness**.)

Comment: Yes, every linear order $X$ admits a completion, called the **Dedekind-MacNeille completion**: you do this with Dedekind cuts, including the "improper" ones $(\varnothing, X)$ and $(X,\varnothing)$, which gives you the top and bottom elements.

Comment: David: please feel free to ask another question, if you like...

Comment: The fixed point property is usually defined as "every continuous self-map has a fixed point". If you don't assume that the function is increasing, then connectedness is not redundant.

Comment: @Niels: Hi there.  For a topological space, I would interpret the fixed point property as you did.  For a linear order, Knaster-Tarski is the first "fixed-point property" that came to my mind, but yes, one could also mean continuous functions.  I *hope* that since my answer was accepted, I interpreted the question correctly. If not, the OP should unaccept and clarify.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen I am interested in both cases actually.  Let me edit my question to distinguish between the two types of fixed point property.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark "weakly increasing functions are continuous in the order topology" - Why would an increasing function $\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ with a jump discontinuity not be a counterexample?

Comment: @David: Oops!  You're right; I was working too quickly.  I will have to delete the second part of my answer for now.